# Need clarification on scope of Friend and Protected Friend

Tags: .net, scope, friend, protected

Okay, I'm having some headaches regarding the `Friend` and `Protected Friend` qualifiers. The information I read everywhere looks like legal language to me. Some like simpler legal language, but still legal language.

So, I'll try to provide a framework of thought in pseudo-VB:

Suppose I have **AssemblyOne**:

```
Public Class classA_One
  Public memberPub
  Private memberPriv
  Protected memberProt
  Friend memberFri
  ProtectedFriend memberProFri
End Class

Public Class classAB_One
  Inherits classA_One
  ...
End Class

Public Class classC_One
  Dim objA_One as classA_One
End Class
```

Someone else (a colleage) takes my generated .dll, references it, and creates **AssemblyTwo**:

```
Public Class ClassAD_Two
  Inherits classA_One
  ...
End Class

Public Class classE_Two
  Dim objA_One as classA_One
End Class
```

What I want to know is the visibility of the members of `classA_One`. I am sure that:

- `memberPub` is visible everywhere
- `memberPriv` can be seen only within `classA_One`
- `memberProt` can be seen in `classA_One`, `classAB_One`, and `classAD_One`

What I'm not sure is the visibility of the other two members of `classA_One`.

Can someone help me?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Friend`: means that it is accessible to any type inside your assembly no one referencing you assembly will be able to see it.

`Protected Friend`: means that the type is only accessible by derived members or your assembly types not derived or not part of your assembly will not be able to access it.

memberFri: is accessible to classAB_one and all other in assembly classes

memberProFri: is accessible to classAB_one but not in classC_one

Comment: imho: memberProFri is accessible to classAB_One, classC_One, classAD_Two, but not classE_Two.